# Global.asax file not giving Exception Message

Tags: asp.net, email, global-asax

Here's my problem I have some code and I'm using it to send an e-mail with the last error details but all I want is the (Inner)Exception Message to be displayed in the email with the URL

Here's my code

```
    Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

' Get current exception 
    Dim err As System.Exception = Server.GetLastError

    Dim ErrorDetails As String = err.Exception.Message

    Dim ErrorURL As String = Request.Url.ToString()

    ' Send notification e-mail
    Dim Email As MailMessage = _
        New MailMessage("email@email.co.uk", email@email.co.uk")
    Email.IsBodyHtml = False
    Email.Subject = "WEB SITE ERROR"
    Email.Body = ErrorDetails & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & ErrorURL
    Email.Priority = MailPriority.High
    Dim sc As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("localhost")
    sc.Send(Email)

End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `err.ToString()` - this gives you the full strack trace and inner exceptions.

If you really only want the inner exception error message, use `err.InnerException.Message`

Comment: The err.InnerException.Message doesn't seem to show anything in the email is it because it's null? And why would it be null from an error?

Comment: @Jamie Taylor - possibly becuase you are catching a primary exception and there _is_ no inner exception. That's why using `err.ToString()` is better in order to get the full details.

Comment: I understand now - if there is an innerexception then it does pass it - i'm struggling to understand what an innereception is though?

Comment: An Inner Exception is just another exception that happened further into the Stack.  For example, a `NullReferenceException` could be thrown, caught, and then a new custom `ApplicationException` be thrown that includes the `NullReferenceException` as its InnerException, allowing you to see the original exception, but then also any further context that has been added to the `ApplicationException`

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("me@me.com"));
msg.From = new MailAddress("from@me.com");
msg.Subject = "My app had an issue...";
msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(ctx.Request.Url.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine);
sb.Append("Source:" + System.Environment.NewLine + ctx.Server.GetLastError().Source.ToString());
sb.Append("Message:" + System.Environment.NewLine + ctx.Server.GetLastError().Message.ToString());
sb.Append("Stack Trace:" + System.Environment.NewLine + ctx.Server.GetLastError().StackTrace.ToString());
msg.Body = sb.ToString();

//CONFIGURE SMTP OBJECT
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("myhost");

//SEND EMAIL
smtp.Send(msg);

//REDIRECT USER TO ERROR PAGE
Server.Transfer("~/ErrorPage.aspx");
}
```